# Bootstrap 4 - left column width changes, depending upon content of right column

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, grid, bootstrap-grid

I obviously don't know enough bootstrap. My objective is to have a layout like this, once "Load Report" button is clicked and there is some data to report:

[image]

Above, there are two columns, first one contains four drop down lists and one button; and the second column contains a table.

When this page is first loaded the table (in right column) should not be there, only left-column should show up. But when I first load the page, I see the left column shrunken like this:
[image]

In this condition, if I hover my mouse on "Load Report" button, I notice that only left half of the button is clickable. And I am guessing that is because it falls directly under the shrunken drop down lists. The right half of butten doesn't respond to hover or click actions. But once, right column (table) is loaded (like in first picture), then entire button becomes clickable and all drop down lists assume the desired size.

If the right column contains anything that occupies lesser width than what is shown, then left column expands only by a percentage relative to the width of right column.

My understanding is that, once I say col-md-2, it should direct bootstrap to grant 2 out of 12 spaces to the left column and any component that I put in there should expand/resize to fit this space. Is that not right? I do not understand why this is happening. Any suggestions?

**Code Detail**

I am doing this in angular, so html is spread over multiple conponents. App component is like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Ticket Status Report</h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <app-ticket-report></app-ticket-report>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ticket Report Component is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2"> 
    <!-- Left Column Code Goes Here -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <!-- Right Column Code Goes Here -->
</div>
</div>
```

**Notes**

1. I've tried this in Chrome and Firefox, both. So browser dependency is ruled out.
2. I'm assuming that since I have given "container" div in App component, I don't have to do it again inside ticket report component.

Comment: one solution is you can conditionally giving class name using `[ngClass]`, 1. `col-md-6` when right side is not visible and 2. `col-md-2` when right side is visible .

Answer (score 0):

The resulting nested `.row` within another `.row` may be causing problems.
Try changing the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Ticket Status Report</h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <app-ticket-report></app-ticket-report>
    </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Ticket Status Report</h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <app-ticket-report></app-ticket-report>
</div>
```

***OR***, remove the containing `.row` from the ticket report:

```
<div class="col-md-2"> 
    <!-- Left Column Code Goes Here -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <!-- Right Column Code Goes Here -->
</div>
```